# How to Retrieve Basic Information in Application Proxy SSL Certificate using Graph API?

Tags: azure, powershell, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-application-proxy

I am able to retrieve most of the information from the Azure Portal using the Graph API through a PowerShell script with the Invoke-RestMethod such as basic information (name, certificate thumbprint and certificate expiration) from SAML Certificate except below.

Currently, I'm attempting to retrieve a basic information in SSL Certificate from the Application Proxy of an app located within the Enterprise Application (kindly refer to the attached image) such as Subject, Certificate Thumbprint and Certificate Expiration.

I've searched for documentation on this, but I found one that relies on a module, [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/scripts/powershell-get-all-app-proxy-apps-extended)

I do want to avoid using modules and instead use the Graph API with the Invoke-RestMethod in PowerShell.

My question is: Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how to retrieve this data such as Subject, Thumbprint and Expiration Date of SSL Certificate only in Application Proxy from the image below using the Graph API and Invoke-RestMethod in a PowerShell script? Thank you in advance!

[A sample pic of SSL Cert from App Proxy Enterprise App in Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T8qg.png)

Comment: You can't.  Certificates are loaded on client and server and never transferred between the client and server.  You may be able to get the names of the certificates, but not the encryption keys in the certificate.

Comment: Apologies @jdweng, I was able to retrieve the basic information from SAML Certificate such as name, thumbprint and SAML certificate expiration. But this SSL Certificate from Application Proxy, I cant get these. i do only want to retrieve the subject, thumbprint and expiration of that ssl cert fron app proxy. Does this possible for the mentioned attributes for retrieval? Thanks!

Comment: I mean do you have any idea on how to retrieve those? It seems I cant find any documentation for this from my end. thanks!

Comment: Search Web "powershell get certificate expiration date"

Comment: @jdweng - I am refering the SSL certificate on the picture from the Application Proxy of an Enterprise App in Azure Portal not the local machine one.

Answer (score 0):

I've found what I am looking for.

To access the basic information of the SSL Certificate of an Application Proxy in Enterprise App from Azure portal using Graph API, use this url endpoint below. It is located under

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/(app object ID here)/onPremisesPublishing
```

The documentation of the mentioned url endpoint doesn't exist from the documentation where I've found the /onPremisePublishing, which is located [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onpremisespublishing?view=graph-rest-beta)

The permission though is not defined on the documentation, but it works for application.read.all permission alone.